# Collaborate over a LAN

Tags: website, collaboration

A co-worker and I are required to build an HTML based website (no PHP, no ASP.net, etc.).  Is there anyway for us to work in the same files/projects across our LAN?  Live edits would be the best, any other system would be acceptable, however.

Comment: Are you looking for collaborative live editing software, or information around version control? You could use a local `git` or `svn` or `mercurial` repository and that would help resolve edit confilcts, but that wouldn't be the same as simultaneous collaborative editing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do these systems prevent edit conflicts?  I might just ask you to post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Version Control software](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Revision_control), specifically I like [git](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Git_%28software%29). Basically, by using source control, both of you can edit files, and if you happen to make edits on the same file that conflict, the VCS will let you know and allow you to manually merge the changes. For most edits, the software is pretty good at automatically merging changes you both make. It'll make sure you don't destory each other's work, and make it easy to revert back to an earlier version of the files (website in this case) in case you mess something up. Also you can use branching to test out different ideas/features and and merge them back to the mainline if you like them/they work.

Other VCS include [Mercurial](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mercurial) and [Subversion](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Subversion) (there are many more). I'd recommend git because it has decent cross-platform support, well documented, and well used, so it's pretty easy to find some good guides/help for it. Here are a few:

- http://book.git-scm.com/index.html
- http://www.gitready.com/

Comment: This pretty much sums it up, except that for beginner, really small projects (2 people in this case, only HTML) I would recommend subversion with TortoiseSVN. I find that it's easier for people to grasp, and the nice explorer extensions mean that you don't have to worry about using the command line.

Comment: I would suggest having it hosted on one of the free sites such as Assembla. It's easier to set up, they take care of backups, and you can use it from anywhere.